# Cannot add CSS class to views field

Tags: views

I have a view in Drupal 8, and have configured a field in the view to have a custom CSS class.

The field I am adding the class to is an image. Under Style Settings I have chosen "Customize field HTML" and "Create CSS class".

[image]

When I inspect the image element on the front end, the class is nowhere to be found, and the styles are not applied.

I also have a view fields template for this view named: 
**views-view-fields--home-page-top-three-stories.html.twig**

```
{{ fields.field_story_preview_image.content }} 
<div class="story-title-box">
    <h3>{{ fields.title.content}}</h3>
    <h4>{{ fields.field_subtitle.content }}</h4>
</div>
```

"fields.field_story_preview_image.content" is the image field that I would like to apply the CSS class to. Am I missing a configuration step?

Why isn't the CSS class being applied to this image field?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue: Drupal 8; a view that includes an image field; same style settings applied. I also can't get Drupal to actually render the class="" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope you cleared cached
2. I hope u added css under [themename].library.yml
3. If still not working plz use rewrite result add your custom html.

Comment: I have cleared the cache, my css has been added under [themename].library.yml, and im not sure about rewrite result, I will explore that now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have modified the template that actually prints the `preview image field classes`

If you have modified the original `views-view-field.html.twig` in your theme than make sure that the `{{ field.element_attributes }}` is included as it is the one responsible for printing the attributes (which includes the classes)

For reference I am pasting here the original `views-view-field.html.twig`

```
{% for field in fields -%}
  {{ field.separator }}
  {%- if field.wrapper_element -%}
    <{{ field.wrapper_element }}{{ field.wrapper_attributes }}>
  {%- endif %}
  {%- if field.label -%}
    {%- if field.label_element -%}
      <{{ field.label_element }}{{ field.label_attributes }}>{{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}</{{ field.label_element }}>
    {%- else -%}
      {{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endif %}
  {%- if field.element_type -%}
    <{{ field.element_type }}{{ field.element_attributes }}>{{ field.content }}</{{ field.element_type }}>
  {%- else -%}
    {{ field.content }}
  {%- endif %}
  {%- if field.wrapper_element -%}
    </{{ field.wrapper_element }}>
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution. My custom theme is a child theme of the Bootstrap 3 theme for Drupal. Within my theme there was no template for views-view-field.html.twig. I have created the template and used the code you provided (from the original), and now none of the view fields across the website appear at all.

Comment: I looked at the original template in core/modules/views/templates and the file you mentioned is views-view-fields.html.twig, not views-view-field.html.twig (plural vs singular). I have copied this template to my custom theme just in case, but still no CSS class on the font end is being applied.